# Is there any WPF DataGrid that natively hands excel clipboard insert?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, clipboard

I mean, I have read features lists of all popular solutions. And they all have export to Excel and ctrl+c to Excel. But what about opposite process?
In my case all the data comes from different sources, mostly in xls and user need to have an easy way for it's input.

Answer (score 1):

The reason most datagrids, including Xceed's, don't provide this capability, is because they are designed to handle tabular data. Another way of saying this is that they are "row-based datagrids" and not "spreadsheet controls". They don't have free-form cells like Excel, where every cell can represent anything and you can have "islands" of data all over the screen, but rather, each column is a specific field that repeats itself on every row.

When you copy stuff from Excel, unless you are thinking of copying an entire row from Excel with the fields in the exact order, to a datagrid, it won't work.

Comment: So - with "entire row copy" it will work?
And what about - couple of rows?